# How to dynamic name definition tool for android?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, definition

I want to define a dynamic TextBox for Android but I do not want to use `foreach`, I just want to do as shown in the pictures using `for`.

[image: Here The picture]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Resources.getIdentifier() to look up the resource id at runtime based on a string.
You can then pass the id it returns into findById.

Of course it's better to just use the id, so only use it if you really need to.  In your example, I would just use the ids instead of constructing a string to look up the id first.